# Comparing two arrays for a matching value

Tags: jquery

I have two arrays. 
The first array `(idContainerArray)` contains the ids of the checkboxes I selected across pages.

The second array `(idArray)` will contain the Ids of the checkboxes of the current page.

I want to compare those two arrays and if a match is found then check the corresponding checkbox on the current page.

The below code execute without errors but won't check the boxes.

jquery :

```
var idArray = [];
        var idContainerArray = [];

       $.each(idArray, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, idContainerArray) != -1) {
                   $(el).prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not quite selecting the DOM element correctly.  `el` should be `'#' + el`:

```
$("#" + el).prop("checked", true);
```

[Fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/4wdHg/1/)

**Edit**

Thanks to @Blender, `document.getElementById(el).checked = true` seems a less-roundabout way.

Comment: Or just `document.getElementById(el).checked = true`

Answer (score 2):

You can select the elements in the cross-page list, then filter using the in-page list:

```
var chkBoxes = $("#" + idContainerArray.join(",#"));
chkBoxes = chkBoxes.filter("#" + idArray.join(",#"));
chkBoxes.prop("checked", true);
```

You may be able to omit the filter.  Is it possible for an element that is contained in `idContainerArray` to be used as an id on the current page, but *not* be contained in `idArray`?  Because, if not, you can skip the filter and just do this:

```
$("#" + idContainerArray.join(",#")).prop("checked", true);
```

This works even if the id is reused as something other than a checkbox. The checked property won't hurt or have any side effects if it is written to a non-checkbox element. If the id can be reused, but not as a checkbox, and you don't want to write the `checked` property, you can filter out the non-checkboxes:

```
$("#" + idContainerArray.join(",#")).filter(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Or:

```
$("#" + idContainerArray.join("[type=checkbox],#") + "[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```

This second technique that does not use jQuery's `:checkbox` shorthand might be a hair faster because it will take advantage of the browser's native `querySelectorAll()` call.  On most pages, you wouldn't notice a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` attribute value must be `checked`. And as McGarnagle pointed out the selector for an id is `#`

```
var idArray = [];
    var idContainerArray = [];

   $.each(idArray, function (i, el) {
        if ($.inArray(el, idContainerArray) != -1) {
               $('#' + el).attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
```

Comment: why `attr` and not `prop`?

Comment: attr works with the html attributes and prop works with the DOM properties see the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for more info. After looking it up, as of jQuery 1.6 `.prop("checked", true)` is the same as `.attr("checked", checked")`